# Can I remember instance of object in Django?

Tags: django, django-channels, aiortc

I'm using `django-channels` and `aiortc`, I want to create `server to peer` connection as `WebRTC`.

In my case, if client send the `new-peer` action, then server send the offer.

And after client receive the offer, client send the answer as `new-answer` action.

But server can't remember `peer`, so can't `setRemoteDescription`.

Of course I know server don't remember, but how do I deal with situations where server need to remember instances like mine?

I also looked for session variables, but it seems that only simple values ​​can be stored, and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the instance.

Please provide helpful documents or solutions related to this.

consumers.receive method:

```
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        receive_dict = json.loads(text_data)
        message = receive_dict['message']
        action = receive_dict['action']

        if (action == 'new-peer'):
            # Create Offer
            peer, offer = await create_offer()
            receive_dict['message']['sdp'] = offer
            receive_dict['action'] = 'new-offer'
            receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name'] = self.channel_name
            await self.channel_layer.send(
                self.channel_name,
                {
                    'type': 'send.sdp',
                    'receive_dict': receive_dict
                }
            )
            return None  
        elif (action == 'new-answer'):
            await peer.setRemoteDescription(receive_dict['message']['sdp'])
            receiver_channel_name = receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name']
            receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name'] = self.channel_name

            await self.channel_layer.send(
                receiver_channel_name,
                {
                    'type': 'send.sdp',
                    'receive_dict': receive_dict, 
                }
            )
            return None
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unexpected action value');
```

create_offer function:

```
async def create_offer():
    pc = RTCPeerConnection(RTCConfiguration(iceServers))
    rtsp_video = MediaPlayer(rtsp_test_url)
    relay = MediaRelay()
    pc.addTrack(relay.subscribe(rtsp_video.video))

    @pc.on("connectionstatechange")
    async def on_connectionstatechange():
        print("Connection state is %s", pc.connectionState)
        if pc.connectionState == "failed":
            await pc.close()
    await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer())

    return pc, object_to_string(pc.localDescription)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: django session support saving instance to their session.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).